# Mass Replace commenting code with notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++

Im looking for a Way to Mass Commenting (and the code to undo it) a block of text. Ignoring other parts of the same file; but at the same time respecting some differences in each block.

example block already commented out,

```
Code to keep Above

#1291.5.21 = { #some more text to preserve
#   owner = XXX
#   controller = XXX
#   add_core = XXX
#   remove_core = XXX
#} #some more text to preserve

More code to keep below
```

The XXX would be different in each block, though possibly the same in different files (though just three letters/numbers); for a bit of extra complexity, blocks with exactly XXX ideally would be ignored (and remain commented).

The lone real pointer for the block restrictions is the date(s) = { and the closing  } which would be the same (up to and largely including the # text to save after)

End result of What im looking for.

```
Code to keep Above

1291.5.21 = { #some more text to preserve
    owner = XXX
    controller = XXX
    add_core = XXX
    remove_core = XXX
} #some more text to preserve

More code to keep below
```

bonus points for being able to do it across 4 or all 8 dates with one click. (as they form super blocks)

```
1291.5.21
1291.5.23
1291.5.24
1291.5.26

1444.11.13
1444.11.15
1444.11.16
1444.11.18
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to uncomment lines that don't have a value equal to `XXX`:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^#(?=\d{4}\.\d\d?\.\d\d?|}|\h+(?:owner|controller|add_core|remove_core)\h*=\h*(?!XXX)\w{3}$)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^#                          # beginning of line and # sign
(?=                         # positive lookahead
    \d{4}\.\d\d?\.\d\d?         # date
  |                         # OR
    }                           # closing curly brace
  |                         # OR
    \h+                         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    (?:                         # non capture group
        owner                       # literally
      |                         # OR
        controller                  # literally
      |                         # OR
        add_core                    # literally
      |                         # OR
        remove_core                 # literally
    )                           # end group
    \h*=\h*                     # equal sign wth optional spaces before and after
    (?!XXX)                     # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't XXX after
    \w{3}                       # 3 word characters
    $                           # end of line
)                           # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: That seems to work for the undoing part, but im also looking for the Doing part :/ up'd noless

Also there can be more than just these dates doing actions, Not sure if that would mess up anything.

Comment: @PirateAE: For commenting just change `^#` at the beginning of the regex into `^` alone and put in the replacement `#`